# PHP Artisan migrate shows a lot of JavaScript error

Tags: laravel, composer-php, database-migration

I have been trying to migrate a new table inside Laravel. After I type

```
php7.1 artisan migrate
```

it shows this

```
r=n(55),o=n(1).has,i=n(1).isValidEntityCode,a=n(1).fromCodePoint,s=/^&#((?:x[a-f0-9]{1,6}|[0-9]{1,7}));/i,c=/^&([a-z][a-z0-9]{1,31});/i;t.exports=function(t,e){var n,u,l=t.pos,f=t.posMax;if(38!==t.src.charCodeAt(l))return!1;if(l+1<f)if(35===t.src.charCodeAt(l+1)){if(u=t.src.slice(l).match(s))return e||(n="x"===u[1][0].toLowerCase()?parseInt(u[1].slice(1),16):parseInt(u[1],10),t.pending+=i(n)?a(n):a(65533)),t.pos+=u[0].length,!0}else if((u=t.src.slice(l).match(c))&&o(r,u[1]))return e||(t.pending+=r[u[1]]),t.pos+=u[0].length,!0;return e||(t.pending+="&"),t.pos++,!0}},function(t,e,n){"use strict";t.exports=function(t){var e,n,r,o,i=t.delimiters,a=t.delimiters.length;for(e=0;e<a;e++)if((r=i[e]).close)for(n=e-r.jump-1;n>=0;){if((o=i[n]).open&&o.marker===r.marker&&o.end<0&&o.level===r.level){var s=!1;if((o.close||r.open)&&void 0!==o.length&&void 0!==r.length&&(o.length+r.length)%3==0&&(o.length%3==0&&r.length%3==0||(s=!0)),!s){r.jump=e-n,r.open=!1,o.end=e,o.jump=0;break}}n-=o.jump+1}}},function(t,e,n){"use strict";t.exports=function(t){var e,n,r=0,o=t.tokens,i=t.tokens.length;for(e=n=0;e<i;e++)o[e].nesting<0&&r--,o[e].level=r,o[e].nesting>0&&r++,"text"===o[e].type&&e+1<i&&"text"===o[e+1].type?o[e+1].content=o[e].content+o[e+1].content:(e!==n&&(o[n]=o[e]),n++);e!==n&&(o.length=n)}},function(t,e,n){"use strict";var r=n(38),o=n(1).isWhiteSpace,i=n(1).isPunctChar,a=n(1).isMdAsciiPunct;function s(t,e,n,r){this.src=t,this.env=n,this.md=e,this.tokens=r,this.pos=0,this.posMax=this.src.length,this.level=0,this.pending="",this.pendingLevel=0,this.cache={},this.delimiters=[]}s.prototype.pushPending=function(){var t=new r("text","",0);return t.content=this.pending,t.level=this.pendingLevel,this.tokens.push(t),this.pending="",t},s.prototype.push=function(t,e,n){this.pending&&this.pushPending();var o=new r(t,e,n);return n<0&&this.level--,o.level=this.level,n>0&&this.level++,this.pendingLevel=this.level,this.tokens.push(o),o},s.prototype.scanDelims=function(t,e){var n,r,s,c,u,l,f,p,d,h=t,m=!0,g=!0,v=this.posMax,b=this.src.charCodeAt(t);for(n=t>0?this.src.charCodeAt(t-1):32;h<v&&this.src.charCodeAt(h)===b;)h++;return s=h-t,r=h<v?this.src.charCodeAt(h):32,f=a(n)||i(String.fromCharCode(n)),d=a(r)||i(String.fromCharCode(r)),l=o(n),(p=o(r))?m=!1:d&&(l||f||(m=!1)),l?g=!1:f&&(p||d||(g=!1)),e?(c=m,u=g):(c=m&&(!g||f),u=g&&(!m||d)),{can_open:c,can_close:u,length:s}},s.prototype.Token=r,t.exports=s},function(t,e,n){"use strict";function r(t){return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1).forEach(function(e){e&&Object.keys(e).forEach(function(n){t[n]=e[n]})}),t}function o(t){return Object.prototype.toString.call(t)}function i(t){return"[object Function]"===o(t)}function a(t){return t.replace(/[.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-]/g,"\\$&")}var s={fuzzyLink:!0,fuzzyEmail:!0,fuzzyIP:!1};var c={"http:":{validate:function(t,e,n){var r=t.slice(e);return n.re.http||(n.re.http=new RegExp("^\\/\\/"+n.re.src_auth+n.re.src_host_port_strict+n.re.src_path,"i")),n.re.http.test(r)?r.match(n.re.http)[0].length:0}},"https:":"http:","ftp:":"http:","//":{validate:function(t,e,n){var r=t.slice(e);return n.re.no_http||(n.re.no_http=new RegExp("^"+n.re.src_auth+"(?:localhost|(?:(?:"+n.re.src_domain+")\\.)+"+n.re.src_domain_root+")"+n.re.src_port+n.re.src_host_terminator+n.re.src_path,"i")),n.re.no_http.test(r)?e>=3&&":"===t[e-3]?0:e>=3&&"/"===t[e-3]?0:r.match(n.re.no_http)[0].length:0}},"mailto:":{validate:function(t,e,n){var r=t.slice(e);return n.re.mailto||(n.re.mailto=new RegExp("^"+n.re.src_email_name+"@"+n.re.src_host_strict,"i")),n.re.mailto.test(r)?r.match(n.re.mailto)[0].length:0}}},u="a[cdefgilmnoqrstuwxz]|b[abdefghijmnorstvwyz]|c[acdfghiklmnoruvwxyz]|d[ejkmoz]|e[cegrstu]|f[ijkmor]|g[abdefghilmnpqrstuwy]|h[kmnrtu]|i[delmnoqrst]|j[emop]|k[eghimnprwyz]|l[abcikrstuvy]|m[acdeghklmnopqrstuvwxyz]|n[acefgilopruz]|om|p[aefghklmnrstwy]|qa|r[eosuw]|s[abcdeghijklmnortuvxyz]|t[cdfghjklmnortvwz]|u[agksyz]|v[aceginu]|w[fs]|y[et]|z[amw]",l="biz|com|edu|gov|net|org|pro|web|xxx|aero|asia|coop|info|museum|name|shop|рф".split("|");function f(t){var e=t.re=n(150)(t.__opts__),r=t.__tlds__.slice();function s(t){return t.replace("%TLDS%",e.src_tlds)}t.onCompile(),t.__tlds_replaced__||r.push(u),r.push(e.src_xn),e.src_tlds=r.join("|"),e.email_fuzzy=RegExp(s(e.tpl_email_fuzzy),"i"),e.link_fuzzy=RegExp(s(e.tpl_link_fuzzy),"i"),e.link_no_ip_fuzzy=RegExp(s(e.tpl_link_no_ip_fuzzy),"i"),e.host_fuzzy_test=RegExp(s(e.tpl_host_fuzzy_test),"i");var c=[];function l(t,e){throw new Error('(LinkifyIt) Invalid schema "'+t+'": '+e)}t.__compiled__={},Object.keys(t.__schemas__).forEach(function(e){var n=t.__schemas__[e];if(null!==n){var r={validate:null,link:null};if(t.__compiled__[e]=r,"[object Object]"===o(n))return!function(t){return"[object RegExp]"===o(t)}(n.validate)?i(n.validate)?r.validate=n.validate:l(e,n):r.validate=function(t){return function(e,n){var r=e.slice(n);return t.test(r)?r.match(t)[0].length:0}}(n.validate),void(i(n.normalize)?r.normalize=n.normalize:n.normalize?l(e,n):r.normalize=function(t,e){e.normalize(t)});!function(t){return"[object String]"===o(t)}(n)?l(e,n):c.push(e)}}),c.forEach(function(e){t.__compiled__[t.__schemas__[e]]&&(t.__compiled__[e].validate=t.__compiled__[t.__schemas__[e]].validate,t.__compiled__[e].normalize=t.__compiled__[t.__schemas__[e]].normalize)}),t.__compiled__[""]={validate:null,normalize:function(t,e){e.normalize(t)}};var f=Object.keys(t.__compiled__).filter(function(e){return e.length>0&&t.__compiled__[e]})
```

**There are a lot of lines in between these two screenshots**

```
nListRow",{attrs:{label:"Message"}},[n("code",{staticClass:"code-block"},[n("pre",[t._v(t._s(t.event.label))])])]),t._v(" "),n("DefinitionListRow",{attrs:{label:"Level"}},[t._v("\n            "+t._s(t.event.metadata.level)+"\n        ")]),t._v(" "),t._l(t.event.context,function(e,r){return n("DefinitionListRow",{key:r,attrs:{label:r}},[t._v("\n            "+t._s(e)+"\n        ")])})],2)],1)},[],!1,null,null,null);e.default=a.exports},function(t,e,n){"use strict";n.r(e);var r=n(90),o=n.n(r),i=n(3),a={components:{DefinitionListRow:n(2).a,DefinitionList:i.a},props:["event"],methods:{formatQuery:function(t){return o.a.format(t)}}},s=n(0),c=Object(s.a)(a,function(){var t=this,e=t.$createElement,n=t._self._c||e;return n("div",[n("DefinitionList",{attrs:{title:"Query"}},[n("DefinitionListRow",{attrs:{label:"Query"}},[n("code",{staticClass:"code-block"},[n("pre",{domProps:{innerHTML:t._s(t.formatQuery(t.event.label))}})])]),t._v(" "),n("DefinitionListRow",{attrs:{label:"Time"}},[t._v("\n            "+t._s(t.event.metadata.time)+"\n        ")]),t._v(" "),n("DefinitionListRow",{attrs:{label:"Connection name"}},[t._v("\n            "+t._s(t.event.metadata.connection_name)+"\n        ")]),t._v(" "),t._l(t.event.context,function(e,r){return n("DefinitionListRow",{key:r,attrs:{label:r}},[t._v("\n            "+t._s(e)+"\n        ")])})],2)],1)},[],!1,null,null,null);e.default=c.exports}]);</script>
<script>
    window.Ignition = window.ignite(window.data);
</script>
<script>
    Ignition.start();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have also tried `composer dump-autoload`

Also, checked my database credentials. They are fine.

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Laravel log shows this

```
Declaration of Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface::setLocale($locale) must be compatible with Symfony\Contracts\Translation\LocaleAwareInterface::setLocale(string $locale) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException(code: 64): Declaration of Symfony\\Component\\Translation\\TranslatorInterface::setLocale($locale) must be compatible with Symfony\\Contracts\\Translation\\LocaleAwareInterface::setLocale(string $locale) at /homepages/24/d521513763/htdocs/OfficePlantsToronto/vendor/symfony/translation/TranslatorInterface.php:24)
```

Comment: there are no screen shots and you can also add some of the lines of the error to your question ... not sure why there would be javascript errors in PHP but also can't see any screenshots

Comment: JavaScript?  Really? It's hard to say...

Comment: @lagbox edited the post. Pasted the error lines.

Comment: check the laravel log in `storage/logs` to see if there is an error logged ... what version of Laravel is this?

Comment: @lagbox I have updated my question. It shows laravel's log.

Comment: what version of Laravel is this supposed to be you are using?

Comment: @lagbox I am using Laravel 6.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is Laravel 6.x requires PHP >= 7.2.

You are using different versions of PHP it would seem as you wouldn't have been able to install Laravel 6 without PHP >= 7.2 originally.

You need to have a newer version of PHP than 7.1 to get around this issue.

Some references on github:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/30655

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/34506

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/34482

Comment: THANKS!!... tried ```php7.3 artisan migrate``` solved the problem

Comment: awesome .. PHP 7.3 should be perfect